# Socket Gateway provide and error in nodes modules

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I want to make a simple gateway in my project using websocket. I have an issue with NestJs when I want to make it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAwoi.png)

```
import { 
    SubscribeMessage, 
    WebSocketGateway, 
    WebSocketServer, 
    OnGatewayDisconnect,
    ConnectedSocket,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class ChatGateway { //implements OnGatewayDisconnect {

    constructor() {}

    @WebSocketServer() server : Server;

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWeby.png)

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ChatService } from './chat.service';
import { ChatGateway } from './chat.gateway';

@Module({
  providers: [
            ChatService,
            ChatGateway
        ]
})
export class ChatModule {}
```

And I got this error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hIYM.png)

```
/Users/mlecherb/transcendance-1/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/gateway-metadata-explorer.js:13
            .getAllMethodNames(instancePrototype)
             ^
TypeError: this.metadataScanner.getAllMethodNames is not a function
    at GatewayMetadataExplorer.explore (/Users/mlecherb/transcendance-1/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/gateway-metadata-explorer.js:13:14)
    at WebSocketsController.subscribeToServerEvents (/Users/mlecherb/transcendance-1/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/web-sockets-controller.js:33:61)
    at WebSocketsController.connectGatewayToServer (/Users/mlecherb/transcendance-1/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/web-sockets-controller.js:30:14)
    at SocketModule.connectGatewayToServer (/Users/mlecherb/transcendance-1/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:47:35)
    at /Users/mlecherb/transcendance-1/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:36:38
    at IteratorWithOperators.forEach (/Users/mlecherb/transcendance-1/backend/node_modules/iterare/src/iterate.ts:202:13)
    at SocketModule.connectAllGateways (/Users/mlecherb/transcendance-1/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:36:14)
    at /Users/mlecherb/transcendance-1/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:31:61
    at ModulesContainer.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SocketModule.register (/Users/mlecherb/transcendance-1/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:31:17)
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

I already tried to make it the shortest possible, I have download all the package necessary.

Comment: I solved this issue by downgrade my version of @nestjs/platform-socket.io and @nestjs/websockets to 9.2.1. I just had to run : 
npm install @nestjs/platform-socket.io@9.2.1 @nestjs/websockets@9.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this version
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "9.2.1",
"@nestjs/websockets": "9.2.1",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

- delete node_modules
- delete pack-lock.json
- then install the packages using npm i --legacy-peer-deps
  this resolved my issue same as yours